# Core data: I/O error for the Database while modifying the coredata model

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data

I have lot of `entities` in my core data, I have added some `attributes` to the different entities at the time of creating the core data. After few days(now) I have added few `new attributes` to the one of my old Entity. when I run the project,

**I got this error:**

> NSUnderlyingException = "I/O error for database at /Users/sagar/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/D4721238-E6FA-4F9E-9F64-BB227399454A/Documents/sagar.sqlite.  SQLite error code:1, 'near \".\": syntax error'";
>
> Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)"

I have reset the simulator, run it again still I am getting the same error.

please help me some one